# Why is 十面埋伏 related to the number 10?

Tags: culture

How does that count?

As we know, Chinese directions can be categorized as 六合八方, but none of them is related to the number 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KEY defines:
十面
as:
(on) all sides, (from) all sides

Also from a Baidu Zhidao question:
十面指的东,南,西,北，东北，东南，西北，西南,上，下

Ten sides: east, south, west, north, north-east, south-east, north-west, south-west, above, below

Comment: I think "十" meaning "complete, perfect" is the intention. The Baidu Zhidao theory sounds dubious because it's mixing 六合 and 八方 directions.

Comment: @congusbongus you have reason, but in real life we normally say 四面埋伏. I had had thought that there to be a specific story for that expression...

Comment: @user3685 "四面埋伏" isn't a chengyu. Sounds like an eggcorn or mistaken for 四面楚歌, which is a synonym. 十面埋伏 is often associated with 垓下之战.

Answer (score 4):

古文中这类数词多有虚指之意，例如“三番五次”是指“许多次”而非“3+5=8次”，“士别三日，当刮目相看”也不是真的隔了“3天”而是一段时间。“十面埋伏”应该也不是严格意义上的“十面”，而是到处都是埋伏的意思吧。

---

*Translation*: In ancient China, these kinds of numbers have abstract meanings.  For example 三番五次 means "many times" not "3+5 = 8 times", and 士别三日，当刮目相看 also is not separation for 3 days, but rather a period of time.

十面埋伏 also should not be strictly interpreted as "10 faced" but rather ambushes are everywhere.

Comment: “士别三日”是因为典故里面就是实打实的三天吧。。。十面埋伏是古曲，所以我想是不是也专门有个典故的说。